# Spring Boot on Appengine standard doesn't start

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

I created a simple ( and almost empty ) spring boot project, I packaged into a jar and I deployed it on appengine.
But it doesn't start!
When I run https://.appspot.com I Have a 500 error page

I saw the database was created and the tables too, but there is something wrong into application

These are the last few lines of the log

Started VibesCoreApplication in 9.729 seconds (JVM running for 11.147)
Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

this is a part of the `pom` file

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!--    for GAE     -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--    for GAE  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sqladmin</artifactId>
            <version>v1beta4-rev76-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

this is the `app.yaml` file

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F2

env: standard

network:
  session_affinity: true

entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar target/vibes-core-0.4.0.jar

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|env))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

here there is the full [logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SpdKOLfgwHu5RHs4jyh91ks7j2DyzZv_JCblQpeRn5w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems like a Spring configuration issue. Do you use the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotations in your app?

Comment: @AndreiTigau yes I do. I also use `@SpringBootApplication` annotation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a similar issue with yours [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14687). The fact is that ( even this should not happen ) the configuration loading order may be broken.

In the post that I have sent you, the solution was removing the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.

Comment: I removed `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and left only `@SpringBootApplication` and nothing has changed...

Comment: Could you please share some code and the application.properties if it is the case? I still think it is something about configurations, as I really don't think you can miss so many classes. Thanks